# configuring IIS server to work with application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

i created an asp.net web app and it works fine with the compiler.

i would like to try it now with IIS server.

i installed the IIS server succesfully on my machine and was wondering if i can have some guidance on redirecting the application to work on it,

how would i get it to work on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just open IIS configuration manager and create a Virtual Directory that points to the folder where you have the web.config and the bin subfolder.

After that you can do right click on the virtual directory on the left treeview, under My Web Site and click browse to open the site with the default browser.

this in twp sentences, to configure security, application pools and much more you should just google and read a bit of basic IIS doc.

Comment: thank you very much i just did this and it gave me this You are not authorized to view this page 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Please try the following:

Click the Refresh button to try

Comment: HTTP 401.3 - Access denied by ACL on resource
Internet Information Services